# Show by mathematical induction that the $\gcd(n,n+1) = 1$ for every integer $n$.

Tags: number-theory

By mathematical induction, how would you show $\gcd(n,n+1)= 1$ for every integer $n$?

I'm thinking you would start by knowing that some integer, $d$, would divide both $n$ and $n+1$. That's all I have so far.

Comment: Can you please edit this post to include what you've tried so far?

Comment: If you're required to use induction, so be it. But there are very easy direct proofs that don't.

Comment: Induction is a terrible way to prove this, FWIW.

Comment: Here is a proof by induction. Suppose that $\gcd(k,k+1)=1$. We show that $\gcd(k+1,k+2)=1$. Suppose to the contrary that some $d\gt 1$ divides both. Then $d$ divides $(k+2)-(k+1)$, so $d$ divides $1$, impossible. So now we have proved the induction step. Of course we have not **used** the induction hypothesis!

Comment: - No induction is needed here, knowing that minimal difference of two numbers sharing same prime divisor is 2, where divisor equals 2.

Comment: The easiest way to prove the claim WITHOUT induction is that the gcd of $n$ and $n+1$ must divide the difference, which is $1$, so the gcd must be $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas If the induction hypothesis isn't being used, is it "really" induction?

Comment: Technically it is.  We have proved that $A(k)$ implies $A(k+1)$.

Comment: Suppose that $\text {gcd}\ (k,k+1) = 1.$ Need to show that $\text {gcd}\ (k+1,k+2) = 1.$ Let $d = \text {gcd}\ (k+1,k+2).$ Then $d\ |\ k+1$ and $d\ |\ k+2.$ But then $d\ |\ 2(k+1)$ and $d\ |\ k + 2.$ Which implies $d\ |\ (2(k+1) - (k+2)) = k.$ So $d\ |\ k$ and $d\ |\ k+1$ and hence $d\ |\ \text {gcd}\ (k,k+1) = 1.$ This shows that $d = 1.$ Now it uses induction hypothesis. Am I right @AndréNicolas?

Comment: Using induction for this is like shooting rockets on ants.

Answer (score 1):

$Proof \ by \ Induction$:

$Base \ case$: $n=0, \ n+1=1$. $\;$ $x\mid$$n$ for all $x$$\in$$\mathbb{Z}$, and $1\mid$$1$  trivially holds. Since the only common divisor is 1, $\gcd(0,1)=1$ holds.

$Inductive \ Hypothesis$: Assume $\gcd(k,k+1)=1$ for some $k\in$$\mathbb{Z}, \ k>0.$

Let $d=\gcd(k+1,k+2)$, where $d\in$$\mathbb{Z}, \ d>0.$ Hence, $d\mid$$(k+1)$ and $d\mid$$(k+2)$. Furthermore, $(k+1)=dm$, for $m$$\in$$\mathbb{Z}$, $0<m\leqslant(k+1)$. Also, $k+2=(k+1)+1=dm+1.$ Since $dm=(k+1)$, we get $(dm-1)=k$. Hence, $\gcd(dm-1,dm)=$$\gcd(k,k+1)=1$, by *inductive hypothesis*.

Edit: Also, since $d=\gcd(k+1,k+2)$$=\gcd(dm,dm+1)$$=\gcd(dm,d(m+\frac1d))$, we get that $\frac1d$ is an integer.

Thus, $\gcd(dm-1,dm)=$$\gcd(d(m-\frac1d),dm)=1$, and it follows that $0<d\leqslant1$. Hence, $d=1$.
Therefore, $\gcd(k+1,k+2)=1$.

Comment: $gcd(dm − 1, dm) = gcd(d(m − \frac{1}{d}), dm) = 1$ -- You can't do that _unless_ you already know that $d|1$ (otherwise $\frac{1}{d}$ is not an integer), which makes it circular.

Comment: I made an edit above, noting that $\frac1d$ is an integer whenever $d=gcd(k+1,k+2)$.

Comment: That's arguably better after the edit, but you are basically doing the manipulation on $gcd(k+1, k+2)$ now, and once you conclude that $\frac{1}{d}$ is an integer it means that $d|1$ and the proof can stop right there, without needing to use the _inductive hypothesis_ any longer.

Comment: That is true, and I'm not sure how else the hypothesis can be used.

Comment: Right. As noted already, the problem (a) doesn't naturally lend itself to an inductive proof, while (b) it has an obvious and straightforward non-inductive proof.

Comment: If $\text {gcd}\ (k+1,k+2) = d.$ Then there exist positive intergers $m_1$ and $m_2$ such that $k+1 = d m_1$ and $k+2 = d m_2.$ But on the other hand $k+2 = (k+1) + 1 = d m_1 + 1.$ Hence we must have $d m_2 = d m_1 + 1$ i.e. $d(m_2 - m_1) = 1,$ which shows that $d\ |\ 1.$ Hence $d = 1,$ as required. By the same way one can contradict the induction hypothesis if $d \gt 1.$

Comment: Suppose that $\text {gcd}\ (k,k+1) = 1.$ Need to show that $\text {gcd}\ (k+1,k+2) = 1.$ Let $d = \text {gcd}\ (k+1,k+2).$ Then $d\ |\ k+1$ and $d\ |\ k+2.$ But then $d\ |\ 2(k+1)$ and $d\ |\ k + 2.$ Which implies $d\ |\ (2(k+1) - (k+2)) = k.$ So $d\ |\ k$ and $d\ |\ k+1$ and hence $d\ |\ \text {gcd}\ (k,k+1) = 1.$ This shows that $d = 1.$ Now it uses induction hypothesis. Am I right?